# Generic dashboard state on Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I have a entity admin table that navigates to a dashboard state for a specific row on row click.
I want to have a default dashboard state and on row click populate the dashboard with the data of the device. This needs to be repeated for multiple devices.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the state entity. In your row click action, if you are using a simple logic one, be sure to tick the "Set entity from widget" checkbox.

Then in the target dashboard state, you need to include an entity alias as below.
[image: State Entity Alias]

Text desc of image:
Alias Name: state entity
Filter Type: Entity from dashboard state
Resolve as multiple: False
Others: None (leave empty)

This will mean that all widgets using this alias will dynamically change based on the current "state entity". You can change the state entity multiple ways, but I recommend to minimise the places that you do this. It can get complicated fast.

If you are not using a simple widget action, and instead using a custom widget action, you will need to use the following code to set the state entity.

```
function updateDashboardState(stateId, label) {
    var params = {
        entityId: entityId,
        entityName: entityName,
        entityLabel: label, // Optional
    };
    // Line below opens new state
    widgetContext.stateController.openState(stateId,
        params, false);
    // Line below updates state
    // widgetContext.stateController.updateState(stateId,
        params, false);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks.. now if I want to add more colums to the entity admin table itself how would I do it

Comment: Add more datasources. Here is a link to the Thingsboard youtube channel, you should watch their videos. They cover many of the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0io1YnQjIwA